# How to make a function jitted with nopython = True if there's use of pandas to read_csv inside the function?

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to make some computations fast using numba's @njit. There is a function in my code, call it, `fn1`(alias) which needs to be jitted. This `fn1` calls another function `fn2`(alias). In my understanding, both functions needs to be jitted.

I am posting below a similar function to `fn2`. The below code doesn't comply to minimum reproducible example as it requires reading csv files and just to be used to understand essence of the question.

```
@njit 
def calculate_prob(list_of_value):
  list_to_return = []
  for xx in list_of_value:
    xdf = pd.read_csv(r'../corpus/{}.csv'.format(xx))
    # do computations with xdf data and get a probability value pr. 
    list_to_return.append(pr)
  return list_to_return
  
  calculate_prob(list_of_value)
```

I also tried to do a POC(see function `test_value`, to see if numpy ndarray was supported by numba but it is also not working for me. I was hoping to convert dataframes to numpy ndarray in preprocessing step and then pass them to my `fn2` as input parameter.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c'], data = [[1,'a',3],[2,'b',4]])

@njit 
def test_value(df_np):
  print(df_np[:,0])

test_value(df.to_numpy())
```

My question is- Is it possible to read a csv file inside a jitted function?(which i think is not possible), and if no, can someone suggest what all options I am left with?

Thanks.

Comment: Numba does not accept `object` ndarrays, you need to provide each column as separate array (or group integer and character columns). And of course it is not possible to read .csv in numba

Comment: @dankal444 Ahh ok. Is there any other, more clean way possible in your knowledge? There are 8000 unique CSVs present and then dealing with their columns would become bit messy I believe. If none, then I will move forward with your suggested approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly manipulate Pandas dataframes in a Numba function. This is explicitly [stated in the first page of the documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html). There is an experimental `objmode` so to execute arbitrary python code like `pd.read_csv` but the main problem is about the type of variables like `xdf` or `list_to_return`: Numba cannot type them (at least not yet). Types are mandatory to compile a Numba function (this is what makes Numba fast compared to CPython).

The main way to fix this is to **put the computational work in a specific function operating on Numpy array**. If your dataframe contains a variable number of columns with dynamically-defined heterogeneous types, then it is not possible to directly compute the dataframe with a Numba function. The reading part cannot be in a Numba function unless the dataframe do not escape a well-defined region (that will not be jitted). Note that you can convert the dataframe to a Numpy array, compute it with Numba and then convert the result back to a dataframe (with some additional overheads).

Comment: Thanks. If you could please elaborate this part  - `` Note that you can convert the dataframe to a Numpy array, compute it with Numba and then convert the result back to a dataframe (with some additional overheads).`` Isn't that I tried to do with df.to_numpy() in my example which did not work.

Comment: Your second example is the typical way to compute dataframes with Numba but the problem is the input dataframe itself: it contains data with an heterogenous type. Thus the Numpy array has a dtype set to `object` preventing any JIT to operate on that (`object` basically means "CPython only"). You need to operate on homogeneous Numpy array with native types. If your dataframe cannot be converted to native types, then there is no way to use Numba (nor any JIT like this).

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the most help I can get in my scenario. Upvoting,